# Apache Spark partitioning and joining

Tags: apache-spark

I understood the benefit of partitioning (splitting data over nodes improve performance of computation ), but i have (a dumb) question. Let's say I have two tables (dummy example for the sake of exposing the problem):

Person :

| ID   | Name   | ZipCode |
|:---- |:------:| -------:|
| 1    | John   | 23      |
| 2    | George | 17      |
| 3    | John   | 1452    |
........

Address

| ZipCode| City      | Country  |
|:------ |:---------:| --------:|
| 23     | London    | UK       |
| 17     | New York  | USA      |
| 1452   | whatever  | whatever |
....

For Person I choose 8 Partitions with some proper lowerBound ,upperBound
For Address I choose 4 Partitions (less data) with some proper lowerBound ,upperBound

My question is: what happened when i do a join between Person and Address and some fancy mathematical formula applied over the result table   ?
If for example i have two physical executors ,  do they need to exchange data (shuffle) to do the proper join ?    If yes, what about when i have a complex SQL with multiple joins and multiple aggregation of data ? Does it make sense to use the partitioning ?

Answer (score 1):

Here are some points about partitioning:

- Partitioning in Spark is when you divide a distributed dataset into smaller datasets to improve processing efficiency.
- You should use partitioning to improve query performance and to avoid data skew when processing large datasets.
- Partitioning enables better resource utilization and improved concurrency for multiple users accessing the same dataset.
- While partitioning can be beneficial, it can also come with some overhead and complexity in maintaining partitions, so it should be evaluated carefully for each use case.